# Why is Screen Resolution (not set) in my Google Analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics, screen-resolution

When I view the reports for Audience -> Technology -> Browser & OS, I see that the data displays like so:

[image]

Does anybody know why Screen Resolution would not be set?

I've heard `https` can meddle with GA variables, but our site does not use `https`.  We have a proprietary sign-on/authentication methods which uses cookies. Unauthenticated users get redirected to our single-sign-on site, but it does not use `https` either.

Thanks for any help on this... just trying to figure out how to report on these visitors.

Comment: Can you drill down to `(not set)` and then check what Browsers are reporting most of the problem? Could help point to a reason. Also, are you doing any kind of non-traditional tracking (besides a standard `ga.js` snippet on the site), like iOS tracking? (Also: It's very unlikely this has to do with HTTPS.)

Comment: Its all over the place. IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari.  IE 8 is the biggest offender with ~90% of those visits, but that is also consistent with our site usage.

Comment: can you drill down to see if javascript was enabled?

Comment: @CrayonViolent, I can't tell if you are trying to be funny. Google Analytics only works on the client side if javascript is enabled.  If you mean is Java enabled, those users also have (not set) for Java and Screen Colors.

Comment: not trying to be funny...depends on what version of GA you are using. Many of the tracking scripts, especially older ones, have a noscript image tag that just sends a static image request so that if a visitor has js disabled, you will still get some basic info like page view

Comment: @CrayonViolent I understand now. No, we have full control of the scripts on this site and all GA JS is used in a master page with the latest async GA snippet. Also, I didn't even see a report showing if javascript is enabled in the new GA interfaces.  Where is that?

Comment: that could be web-crawlers ? search-engines (other than google itself) ?

Comment: Nah, it couldn't be crawlers because its not a public site.  Unauthorized access immediately gets bounced to a separate sign-on site (not tracked above). Thanks tho

Comment: This article may be useful for somebody else researching the issue: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Because they don't have javascript enabled and Google Analytics falls back on an .gif request which doesn't have access to browser capabilities.

[Here is more info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting)

Comment: Care to elaborate on how Google Analytics 'falls back' on a .gif request when javascript is disabled?  Using the async snippet, I do not see `<noscript>` tags.  Thanks.

Comment: I might be wrong, please read more here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gifParameters

Comment: That link is for the topic of debugging analytics tracking issues by using GIF requests.  It does not confirm or address GIF requests as fall-back degradation in the case where Javascript is not enabled.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this party but I found the answer here:

[What is Not Set in Google Analytics Reports](http://www.businesscatalystseo.com.au/seo-tips/what-is-not-set-in-google-analytics)

Essentially, browsers that don't support Flash will trigger this Not Set category under Screen Resolutions. It's not Javascript, or the tracking gif or any of that. Our site does have some Flash on it, and this makes sense then why it shows up.

According to this article, you'll get Not Set in other areas too for other reasons. Hope this helps someone else who stumbles in here.

Comment: This is incorrect. The article is wrong, which you can see by reading the following official source (which doesn't provide an answer either): https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en